# Register or use web service at user control, rather than master page

Tags: c#, user-controls, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

Just trying to see if I can add a definition/register AJAX web service explicitly in a user control that uses it (via client side). Web service is defined and located on the same server as the control(s) that use it, but the control is unable to use it.

It works when I'm adding reference to the web service on SriptManager on the master page, but I want to specifically add it to be used by custom control, and then wan't to remove it from the master page.

Scenario: 
I've tried: 
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxws" Assembly="AssemblyName" Namespace="WebService.AjaxNameSpace"  %>

Let me know if some more details are needed. I've been researching a fix for this, but the only reliable fix I found, is to add the .asmx to ScriptManager on a master page.

Comment: Is JQuery an available option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you are trying to add a script reference or a service reference to your script manager.

You can accomplish this in the code-behind of your user control, using a statement such as:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).Scripts.Add(/* Whatever it is you want to add */);
```

... for which you need the [Script Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference.aspx) class, or ...

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).Services.Add(/* Whatever it is you want to add */);
```

... for which you need the [Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.servicereference.aspx) class.

Note that either approach will give you fits if the page doesn't have a script manager.

Comment: If you want to recommend the Script Manager path, I would just say to "make sure the master page has a ScriptManager" and putting a ScriptManagerProxy on the control. That manages the relationship easily.

Comment: Is there a way to add the ScriptManagerProxy in the .ascx itself without changing the code-behind (avoiding compilation changes). The master page always does have a default ScriptManager. The issue is that only certain controls need to use that web service, so it needn't be available to all the other pages. I have no control over changing the code-behind as well.

Comment: @Amy, the script manager proxy _should_ be added to the .ascx. But this **will** change the compilation. You will have to recompile in order to pick up the new references. The script manager and the proxy coordinate to make sure that a reference is added when you need it to be, but only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use jquery in your solution and you want to work the reference completely from the client side. You can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //You can use POST or GET (GET works a little different)
            url: "YourWebService.asmx/GetSomeData", //This assumes a relative path, you can use any url.
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // you must define the content type (though I am not sure what other options are of any value here...)
            dataType: "json", //you can do json or XML serialization, do json, it is easier in the long run.
            success: Success, //this is a reference to the "function Success" to be invoke by the the service return.
            error: Error //ditto for the function Error...
        });
    }

    function Success(data, status) {
        //do what you want with the data...
    }

    function Error(request, status, error) {
        //something in the soup ain't right...
    }
</script>
```

This is really about as easy as it gets for invoking a web service using ajax and jQuery.

Comment: thank you very much for your inputs. Unfortunately, JQuery is not a preferred option (not me) :( :(